# SymPy Not Doesn't Return LaTeX

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy

Helloo!

So, I'm using SymPy to make a calculation for me. The trouble is, its output should be a LaTeX expression and in make case it prints something like

[SymPy Calculation Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gerjk.png)

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the notebook to use latex.

Try this:

```
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing()
```