# Sympy Does not Recognize LaTex

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, sympy

My output of Sympy in IPython and Jupyter Notebooks does not use LaTex. In IPython it uses even only ASCII and in Notebooks some ugly rendering (if I use regularly LaTex stuff in Markdown everything is normally LaTex).
How can I fix this? I have already tried with the docu and search on the internet and checked related topics like this

[SymPy Not Doesn't Return LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72288639/sympy-not-doesnt-return-latex)

Unfortunately, it doesn't change anything. LaTex is already installed.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Python: 3.10.4

Sympy: 1.7.1

Output in Jupyter-Lab/Notebook:

[image]

Output in DataSpell:

[image]

In Jupyter-Lab it doesn't look "LaTex-like" and the sum for example is bolder.

Comment: In IPython, you can get pretty sympy with the `isympy` startup script.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't change the problem. I edit in my post some pictures to clarify the problem a little bit.